# 401: Not Authorized error only when requesting data using fetch

Tags: node.js, rust, fetch-api, bearer-token, actix-web

I was trying to get response from an API running on localhost, I had gotten a generated bearer token from the login endpoint and now I just wanted to use the token to get the user claims on it. My fetch request is as follows:

```js
const token = "MY_TOKEN";

(async () => {
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/restricted/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    console.log(response.status);
})();
```

This always results in a 401 Unauthorized error.

However if I try do the same request using some other testing client like postman or insomnia or even the thunderbird extension for VS code, it works properly. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Insomnia Working Screenshot]

The middleware for checking the Bearer token is a Rust Actix Web middleware using the jwt_simple package. Here is the code for it as well if it helps:

```rs
use actix_web::{dev::ServiceRequest, web::Data};
use actix_web_httpauth::extractors::{
    bearer::{self, BearerAuth},
    AuthenticationError,
};
use jwt_simple::prelude::MACLike;

use crate::{models::user::User, AppState};

pub async fn validator(
    req: ServiceRequest,
    credentials: BearerAuth,
) -> Result<ServiceRequest, (actix_web::Error, ServiceRequest)> {
    let key = &req
        .app_data::<Data<AppState<User>>>()
        .clone()
        .unwrap()
        .signing_key;
    match key.verify_token::<User>(credentials.token(), None) {
        Ok(_) => return Ok(req),
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Credential Token {} did not verify!", credentials.token());
            let config = req
                .app_data::<bearer::Config>()
                .cloned()
                .unwrap_or_default()
                .scope("home");

            return Err((AuthenticationError::from(config).into(), req));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried setting the `mode` property of fetch to be `"cors"` so far, but the server logs don't say much other than 401 authorized which either means it's having a problem getting the token or the token gets modified at some point.

EDIT: Removed content-type from headers

Comment: Why does your GET request have a content-type header?

Comment: @Philisonstrike my bad I was just test that out of misery, I forgot to remove that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have understood why the problem was happening, in my gateway service, I was **redirecting** all of my requests like so:

```rs
App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .wrap(cors)
            .wrap(ratelimit_middleware)
            .service(ping)
            .wrap_fn(|req, srv| {
                log::info!("{:#?}", req.headers());
                srv.call(req)
            })
            .service(
                web::scope("/auth")
                    .service(web::redirect(
                        "/ping",
                        format!(
                            "http://{}:{}/ping",
                            config_clone.auth_service.address, config_clone.auth_service.port
                        ),
                    ))
)
```

This doesn't work on most HTTP clients, **because the Authorization header is stripped off from the request when a redirect happens, this is due to security reasons by default**.

To fix this, we would have to use the `Client` API for which I used the `awc` crate to copy the headers into a new request and make the request through the gateway service like so:

Add the awc crate:

```bash
cargo add awc
```

Then add the forward request service

```rs
async fn forward_request(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let target_url = "http://authorization-service"; // Replace with the actual URL of the authorization microservice
    let client = awc::Client::default();

    // Create a new request and copy necessary headers
    let forwarded_req = client
        .request_from(target_url, req.head())
        .no_decompress()
        .insert_header((
            "Authorization",
            req.headers().get("Authorization").unwrap().clone(),
        ));

    // Send the forwarded request and return the response
    let mut response = forwarded_req.send().await.unwrap();
    HttpResponse::build(response.status()).body(response.body().await.unwrap())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't specify what type of data the fetch API will return.

> Assuming you expect a return of type JSON, you can edit it as follows

```js
(async () => {
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/restricted/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
    const result = response.json()
   
    console.log(result.status);
})();
```